# Jquery onchange event not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, struts2, jquery-selectors

I am stuck in a situation where I have a Struts2 form with a select tag which when changed should trigger an event and I can't figure out why the `onchange` function is not triggering but the peculiar thing is that the `onchange` trigger event works in an other example. I am confused here.

NOT Working:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>New Order</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function(){
        $('#company').change(function() {
            var selected = $('#company').val();
            alert(selected);
        });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <s:form action="NewOrder">
        <s:select headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Company" name="company"
            label="Select Company" list="{'companies','industries'}" />
    Select Item:
    <select id="item"></select>
        <s:select id="ordertype" name="purchaseorder.orderType"
            list="{'Consumables','Tools','Raw Materials'}" label="Order Type" />

        <s:textfield name="purchaseorder.orderDate" label="Order Date" />

        <s:textfield name="purchaseorder.deliveryDate" label="Delivery Date" />

        <s:textfield name="purchaseorder.exciseDuty" label="Excise Duty" />

        <s:textfield name="purchaseorder.salesTax" label="Sales Tax" />

        <s:textfield name="purchaseorder.remarks" label="Remarks" />

        <s:textfield name="purchaseorder.deliverySchedule"
            label="Delivery Schedule" />

        <s:submit />
    </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Working:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#state').change(function(){
            var sel = $('#state').val();
            alert(sel);
            });
        });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Struts 2 Dynamic Drop down List</h3>
    <s:select label="What's your State" headerKey="-1"
        headerValue="Select State" list="states" name="state" 
        value="defaultState" />
    District :
    <select id="district"></select>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Andrea Ligios Yes sir am trying it out as per your explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#something` selector (both in jQuery and CSS) is the **ID selector**. It means:

> select the object with the `id` attribute equals to `something`.

Since both your `<s:select/>` have no `id` attribute set, it should not work in none of the above case.

However, the explanation to *why it works there and not here* is simple:

Struts2 generates the `id` for you, when it is not specified. The `id` is usually autogenerated in the form of `formName_elementName` (or `formId_elementName`, I'm not sure).

- **First example**:

  since you have a form, the `id` of your select will be something like `id="form1_company"` (or `id="formNewAction1_company"`, I don't remember the way Struts2 generates the `id`/`name` for the forms, since also your `<form>` is missing them !..).
- **Second example**:

  the `<s:select>` is not enclosed in a form, so since its `name` is `"state"`, the autogenerated id will be `id="state"` , and will be matched by the `$('#state')` selector.

---

#### Moral of the story:

**always give your objects an `id`**, at least to the one you need to work with JavaScript.

Comment: I thought the same moral.

Comment: @Andrea Ligios Your solution and explanation solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function(){
        $('#ordertype').change(function() {        //id shoud be orderType not company
            var selected = $('#ordertype').val();
            alert(selected);
        });
    });
```

Comment: I want the onchange event to trigger when the company changes and not on change of ordertype.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I do not see any element that matches #company in the first HTML, BUT I also don't see one that matches #state in the supposedly working example....   so that's confusing.   You have a "select[name=company]" but no select box has an id attribute with value 'company'.

If anything is being dynamically changed on your page, like something loading through ajax (like that id attr being added in) you may need to use this: [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)